# How to correctly solve this situation regarding DataContext, IDisposable and Controls.Clear()

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-4, datacontext, idisposable

I'm using Entity Framework 4 as my ORM on a Windows Forms application.

I have a series of UserControls that function as if they were forms or areas inside my MainForm.cs. The reason I did this was to easily interchange what to display in the 'content' block of the form.

[image]

So when I click on the buttons (on the left), I .Clear() whatever controls is currently in the 'content' block and add the select form.

Here's the relevant code:

```
    private void navigationBar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //panelHolder is a regular Winforms Panel control.
        panelHolder.Controls.Clear();
        switch (sender.ToString())
        {
            case "alumnos":
                var studentForm = new Students.StudentListerForm();
                panelHolder.Controls.Add(studentForm);
                break;
            case "personal":
                var personalForm = new Personal.PersonalListerForm();
                panelHolder.Controls.Add(personalForm);
                break;
            case "atendencia":
                var atendenciaForm = new Attendance.StudentAttendanceForm();
                atendenciaForm.ShowDialog();
                break;
            case "cursos":
                var gradeForm = new Grades.GradeListerForm();
                panelHolder.Controls.Add(gradeForm);
                break;
            case "centralizador":
                MessageBox.Show("est");
                break;
            case "libretas":
                Scores.StudentScores scores = new Scores.StudentScores();
                panelHolder.Controls.Add(scores);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Now, each UserControl manages it's own creation and usage of the data context. Inside of each of these controls I have code for example:

```
using (GradeRepository repo = new GradeRepository())
{
    cmbGrade.DataSource = repo.FindAllGrades();
}
```

And here's the code for GradeRepository:

```
public class GradeRepository : IDisposable
{
    ColegioDBV2Entities db = new ColegioDBV2Entities();

    public IQueryable<Grade> FindAllGrades()
    {
        return db.Grades;
    }        

    public void Add(Grade grade)
    {
        db.AddToGrades(grade);
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        db.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This ensure I use the context, get data, close it and dispose of it.

My problem lies when I click on one of the buttons I told you about up top, the `panelHolder.Controls.Clear();` line fires **[ObjectDisposedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.objectdisposedexception.aspx)**.

I've temporarily solved this by removing the using statements in the relevant areas, so it now looks like:

```
GradeRepository repo = new GradeRepository();
cmbGrade.DataSource = repo.FindAllGrades();
```

Can anybody suggest a correct way to tackle this problem? Will the .Clear() method successfully dispose of any objects, so using a `using` statement is not needed?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the DataContext as a property on the scope of the form and let it destroy when the form is destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

You are likely returning an `IQueryable<T>` which supports deferred execution. This means, you return the `IQueryable<T>` but then dispose the attached `DataContext`. When the `IQuerable<T>` is executed (sometime later), it tries to access the `DataContext` which has now been disposed.  You could probably do this:

```
cmbGrade.DataSource = repo.FindAllGrades().ToList();
```

Comment: This sounds like it could be the root of the issue, but I doubt it is. The exception is being fired clearly on the .Clear() line, so I am relatively sure it's because it's trying to dispose of an object that's already been disposed of. Does this make sense? Thank you for your help though. :)

Comment: It could be exactly the issue. If the `Clear` method is internally calling `Dispose` on any attached controls, then `Dispose` will get fired again..if the control chains the `Dispose` call through to the `DataSource` property.

Comment: Ok, so how do you recommend I handle this? The temporary solution I posted in the question doesn't feel right, but I could be overthinking things. Perhaps Clear method is calling dispose on everything in the UserControl. Can you confirm?

Comment: I would do what I said, if you call `ToList` while in the scope of your `DataContext`, the query is executed and return straight away, which means there is nothing for it to `Dispose` when you call `Clear` later on.